# I want to render movies in a watchlist component, but it won't let me

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built a little movie database and want to display movies to my watchlist. I can search for movies, but when I want to add them to my watchlist, it only gets rendered in my Homescreen component, not in my WatchList component. This is how it looks and what I tried so far. HomeScreen is passing the movies as props to the MovieList component. It will show me all the movies I am searching for. When I now click on the "Add to Watchlist" button, I want the movie to be added to my watchlist (WatchList component). But so far the WatchList component is empty, the movies will only show on my HomeScreen component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import "./HomeScreen.css"
import MovieList from './componnents/MovieList';
import Header from './componnents/Header';
import AddWatchlist from './componnents/AddWatchlist';
import WatchList from './componnents/WatchList';

function HomeScreen() {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    const [watchList, setWatchList] = useState([]);
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');
  
    const getMovieRequest = async (searchValue) => {
      const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchValue}&apikey=93fe1299`;
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const responseJson = await response.json();
  
      if (responseJson.Search) {
        setMovies(responseJson.Search);
      }
    };
  
    useEffect (() => {
      getMovieRequest(searchValue);
    }, [searchValue]);

    const addToWatchlist = (movie) => {
      const newWatchList = [...watchList, movie];
      setWatchList(newWatchList);
    };

  return (
    <div className="HomeScreen">
        <Header searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue}/>
    <div className='movie__row'>
        <MovieList movies={movies} handleWatchlist={addToWatchlist} watchlistComponent={AddWatchlist}/>
    </div>
    <div className='movie__row'>
        <WatchList watchList={watchList}/>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen
```

```
import React from 'react'
import "./MovieList.css"

const MovieList = (props) => {
  const WatchlistComponent = props.watchlistComponent;
  return (
    <>
    {props.movies.map((movie, index) =>
      <div className='image__container'>
        <img src={movie.Poster} alt='movie'></img>
        <div onClick={()=> props.handleWatchlist(movie)} className='add__watchlist'>
          <WatchlistComponent/>
        </div>
      </div>
     )}
    </>
  )
}

export default MovieList;
```

```
import React from 'react'
import "./WatchList.css"

function WatchList({watchList}) {
  if (!watchList) {
    return null;
}

  return (
    <div className='watchlist'>
    <h2>Watch List</h2>
    {watchList.map((movie) => (
      <img src={movie.Poster} />
    ))}
  </div>
);
}

export default WatchList
```

Comment: if create app use your components, will be empty display and text: "Watch List". Please, give me mock data or create your example use CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/. And you wront write word "components"

Comment: There's a little confusion. You have a `WatchList` component on in `Home` but you don't want the list to appear there? But you're also attempting to pass the `WatchList` component into the `MovieList` component (also: `Home`), so it's not really clear what it is you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If add mock value in app component, for example:

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([
    {
      Poster: "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/R/S/Z/4/t/f/crossed-hammers-bw-100x100-md.png",
      text: "hello",
    },
  ]);
```

and rewite component MovieList

```
const MovieList = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {props.movies.map((movie, index) => (
        <div className="image__container">
          <img src={movie.Poster} alt="movie"></img>
          <div onClick={() => props.handleWatchlist(movie)} className="add__watchlist">
            {movie.text}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

And rewrite component WatchList

```
function WatchList({ watchList }) {
  if (!watchList) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="watchlist">
      <h2>Watch List</h2>
      {watchList.map((movie) => (
        <>
          <img src={movie.Poster} />
          {movie.text}
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now when I click on text "Hello" which is above the words "Watch List", I get copy this "movie", and it appears below the phrase "Watch List".

**This is what you need?**

Comment: unfortunately not. It will appear below Watch List, but I want it to appear on a different site., not in HomeScreen

Comment: @Brinda5 what do you mean "a different site"?